# Github actions - $GITHUB_OUTPUT is not setting the value

Tags: github-actions

I have setup like this -

```
name : set variable
id : init
shell : bash
run : |
  echo "url= abc" >> $GITHUB_OUTPUT

name : Get variable
shell : bash
run : |
  echo "${{steps.init.outputs.url}}"
```

but get variable always prints echo "" , i.e. no value.
how do I set the url variable?

Comment: **Syntax error**: missing $ for `{{...}}` (should be `echo "${{ steps.init.outputs.url }}"`)

Comment: See [Expressions](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/learn-github-actions/expressions) for more details. Also, there's a space after = here i.e. `echo "url= abc" >> $GITHUB_OUTPUT`. You might need to remove it.

Comment: space was the issue...thanks